# How to disable function signature suggestion popups in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I disabled all the suggestions options I could find in settings, but this one still pops up.

How could I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te VS Code term for this is signature-help/parameter-hints. To disable them, just set:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled:: false
```

After disabling, you can manually show the parameter hints at the current location using the `Trigger parameter hints` command

Comment: While in the right direction, the spelling and formatting on this could be improved, but the "Suggested edit queue is full" when attempting to edit.
The VS Code settings.json setting is: `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`, and not the above, and to `trigger parameter hints` you can use `CNTRL+SHIFT+SPACE` or `CNTRL+P`.