# How Can I Turn OFF Code Suggestions in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I am writing Python code, I find code autocomplete suggestion in VS Code very helpful.

But I also see this large box "verbose_name:" causing the actual code to hide while I am writing. I dont what is it called.

Does anybody know how to turn it OFF but keep the code autocomplete suggestion ON in VS Code?

Here is a picture of what I see:

[verbose_name: str | bytes .....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPIEJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable function signature suggestion popups in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291379/how-to-disable-function-signature-suggestion-popups-in-vscode)

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I've test in my project and found the following setting still show documentation:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints": false,
```

It looks like this is a known bug in VS Code, see bug report:

> [Bug: the plugin does not respect parameterHints setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7094)